# Can it be made so that I can view the questions I cast my votes on?

Tags: discussion

In my profile, it shows the total amount of votes I have cast, up or down, on questions or on answers. Could I please view the questions or answers which I have voted on? Is it possible that this new gadget be introduced? And make it visible only to me.

Comment: Some related reading on MSO: [Possible to search questions I voted on?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48830/possible-to-search-questions-i-voted-on) ◊ [Is there any way for me to find Stackoverflow questions on which I have cast votes?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27735/is-there-any-way-for-me-to-find-stackoverflow-questions-on-which-i-have-cast-vote) ◊ [Finding the questions/answers that I've voted on](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44764/finding-the-questions-answers-that-ive-voted-on).

Comment: Actually, I'd like to have it made into a subpage, like the way, reputation, responses, and favourites already are.

Comment: There used to be one. Read Jeff's answer to the first question I linked to.

Comment: Seriously Sad...

Answer (score 4):

The system pushed this meta post back to the top of the list and the answer has changed, presumably due to programming changes since 2011.

---

Go to your profile and identify the following line (just below the major boxes near the top) -

> summary answers questions tags badges favorites all actions responses votes

Click on the last link (`votes`) to list the votes that you have cast.

Answer (score 3):

No, this isn't currently possible, nor do we have plans to support such functionality at this time.